# Copy struct to an other

Tags: c, struct, memcpy

I want to copy some data stored in a struct to an other. Does the code below work?? Is it recommended or not?

```
#define SIZE 100
struct {
int *a;
int *b;
} Test;
Test t1;
t1.a = malloc(SIZE);
t1.b = malloc(SIZE);

Test t2;
memcpy(t2,t1,sizeof(Test));
```

Comment: `t2 = t1` would be more correct. But be careful when sharing pointers like that.

Comment: Elaborating on what @DCoder said, In this case you would not be copy the memory of `t1.a` and `t1.b` you would be copying a struct which points to that memory.

Comment: To make sure you're using it correctly, `malloc (100)` will reserve 100 bytes, not 100 ints. Typically, to make it explicit, you'd see `malloc (NUM_ELEMENTS * SIZE_OF_ONE_ELEMENT)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether it works depends on what you intend it to do. It copies the bits from `t1` to `t2`, including padding, but of course it copies the pointers, not the pointed-to values.

If you don't care about the padding bits - and why should you - a simple assignment

```
Test t2 = t1;
```

is all you need to copy the pointers.

If you want the pointed-to values duplicated and copied, neither your code nor simple assignment works.

To copy the pointed-to memory blocks, first of all, you must know their size. There is no (portable) way to find out the size of the pointed-to memory block from the pointer.

If the size is given by a `#define`, you can of course reuse that, otherwise you need to store the sizes of the allocated blocks somewhere.

But since the newly allocated memory blocks have different addresses than the blocks to be copied, we need not copy the pointer vlaues from `t1` to `t2` at all.

```
Test t2;
t2.a = malloc(SIZE);  /* be aware that this is bytes, not number of ints */
t2.b = malloc(SIZE);
if (t2.a == NULL || t2.b == NULL) {
    /* malloc failed, exit, or clean up if possible */
    fprintf(stderr,"Allocation failure, exiting\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/* malloc was successful in both cases, copy memory */
memcpy(t2.a, t1.a, SIZE);
memcpy(t2.b, t1.b, SIZE);
```

Comment: No I need to copy integer data stored in array a and b.

Comment: In that case, you need to `malloc` new memory and copy that, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Is there any way to skip implementing copy function or avoiding loops??